# Why has my IIS stopped serving .html pages?

Tags: iis, iis-7

I'm suddenly getting a rather strange IIS error on my server:

```
There is no build provider registered for the extension '.html'. You can register one in the <compilation><buildProviders> section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.
```

Since when does .html need a build provider???  I haven't touched any build provider or handler mappings.  Haven't touched the default web.config or machine.config from the .NET config directory.

How does a web server forget how to serve HTML???  :(

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your web.config:

```
<buildProviders>
    <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
</buildProviders>
```

You get this error when you try to return the html page from a route handler (or elsewhere) with BuildManager. At least it was like this in my case.